# Fullcalendar custom header in Month and week view

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

Fullcalendar.io has the Option to make [custom ColumnHeaders](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/columnHeaderHtml) in Html.

How can I make a difference between my month and my week view? For the month view i will only display the weekday in the header.

```
 columnHeaderHtml: function (date) {
      const days = ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa'];
      let html = '';
      html += '<span class="column-header-week">' + days[date.getDay()] + '</span>';
      html += '<span class="column-header-day">' + date.getDate() + '</span>';
      return html;
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options

Answer (score 4):

Solution from ADyson works like a charm:
[fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options)

```
views: {
   dayGrid: {//week and day view
     columnHeaderHtml: function (date) {
          const days = ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'];//todo asptext
          let html = '';
          html += '<span class="column-header-week">' + days[date.getDay()] + '</span>';
          return html;
       }
    },
    timeGrid: { //month view         
      columnHeaderHtml: function (date) {
         const days = ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa'];//todo asptext
         let html = '';
         html += '<span class="column-header-week">' + days[date.getDay()] + '</span>';
         html += '<span class="column-header-day">' + date.getDate() + '</span>';
         return html;
     }
 },
```